# Timing of Loading DLLs - Possible to preload DLLs when using Process.Start? C#

Tags: c#, dll

I have several solutions that create .EXEs.  I decided to make a master solution that uses Process.Start("call to .exe")

```
 Accounting  -->  Orders -->  Order Processing.exe
             -->  Receivables -->  Receivables.exe


 Sales       -->  Gross Sales Analysis -->  Sales Analysis.exe
             -->  Reports -->  Reports.exe
```

Some of these exe's use several shared .DLLs (i.e. Crystal Reports).  I would like to load the Crystal Reports DLL in the master solution so it doesn't get reloaded for each .exe    Is that possible?

Comment: Nope, you are launching the processes independently so each one must load the DLL's.

Comment: Rats!  Thank you, @Gusman

Comment: Running ngen over your assemblies might help. First, it will remove overhead of JITting them, and also, as far as I know (though didn't test myself) - windows will be able to share certain parts of such assemblies between different processes that use them, which should reduce memory footprint and also help a bit with loading times.

Comment: The child processes would need to connect back to the master solution.  The connection could be through standard input/output, a pipe, or a Network connection.